# PHP PDO SQL Join two strings together

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to join two strings together in a prepare statement (table name & column which is dynamic) but I am getting

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'exp.$getSkill' in 'field list'
```

My code is:

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT members.*, exp.*, lvl.*, exp.$getSkill AS exp_skill, lvl.$getSkill AS level_skill FROM members INNER JOIN exp ON members.id = exp.member_id INNER JOIN lvl ON members.id = lvl.member_id ORDER BY lvl.$getSkill DESC, exp.$getSkill DESC');   
            $query->execute();
            $row = $query->fetch();
```

Is there a way I can join exp. and $getSkill properly?

Comment: Just to be sure - is `$getSkill` a local variable in your code?

Comment: Yes, it's essentially just a $_GET['']

Comment: If you use simple $variable .. you MUST enclosed string in double quotes `"` !!! Or you can use {$variable}.

Answer (score 0):

Variable aren't evaluated inside strings with single quotes. You'd need to use double quotes, and surround the name with curly braces (`{}`):

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT members.*, exp.*, lvl.*, exp.${getSkill} AS exp_skill, lvl.$getSkill AS level_skill FROM members INNER JOIN exp ON members.id = exp.member_id INNER JOIN lvl ON members.id = lvl.member_id ORDER BY lvl.$getSkill DESC, exp.$getSkill DESC");
```

**Mandatory note:**

Using string concatenation in an SQL query could potentially expose your code to SQL Ijection attacks. You should be **very** careful if you intend to use such a technique.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT members.*, 
                 exp.*,            
                 lvl.*, 
                 exp.'.$getSkill.' AS exp_skill, 
                 lvl.$getSkill AS level_skill 
            FROM members 
               INNER JOIN exp ON members.id = exp.member_id 
               INNER JOIN lvl ON members.id = lvl.member_id 
           ORDER BY lvl.$getSkill DESC, exp.$getSkill DESC';

$query = $db->prepare($query);   
        $query->execute();
        $row = $query->fetch();
```